# Web page designing Changes in little bit in different browser

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on a web application using asp.net. if i runs my web pages in `IE7`
then  design changes little bit compare to `IE8`.
Can u guide me why this difference comes and what is the solution of this problem.

Comment: You should be more explicit, show what difference you find. It would also be useful to know if you're using a doc type. Without that info why cannot guess what is happening in your particular case.

Comment: I was trying to upload images its not giving permission to me to upload image.because i m new user for this site.is there any other way to discuss.

Comment: does your pages have DOCTYPE?

Comment: If your web pages are on a public server then you could paste the links here for folk to review. If your pages aren't public yet then you could use a site like http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a link for review. If you're not familiar with jsfiddle, you'll need to paste the HTML, CSS and JS output from your ASP.NET page into the relevant jsfiddle panes and then "save" to create a link that we can look at.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 render pages a bit differently.  Simple as that.  Just like IE8 renders just a little differently from Firefox, or FF3 from FF2.  The bigest cause of differences is wacky CSS, but even with totally standard styles there is a bit of difference.  Between IE7 and IE8 there was a big push toward more standards-compliant rendering, including slight changes to the box model and such.

First and foremost, be sure your page is rendering in standards mode.  Quirks mode basically means "render this however you feel like", which in IE means "render pretty much like IE5 did".  Adding a `<!DOCTYPE html>` line as the first line in the file should trigger standards mode, if it isn't already there.  After that, address the layout differences.

Ideal solution: have a layout that doesn't look like crap if everything isn't pixel perfect.  It's not really that hard, particularly since layout tables are effectively deprecated.

Suboptimal but functional solution:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

In `ie7.css`, put the little tweaks that would nudge stuff into the right positions in IE7.  Other browsers tend not to need such tweaks if your CSS is done right.